# Apache, Linux 2, Elastic Beanstalk - Rewrite http and www to https non-www

Tags: apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to get URL rewrites as noted in the question title. I created `.platform/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf` and with the below content, I was able to get http to https rewriting successfully.

```
RewriteEngine On
<If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</If>
```

I am now trying to get the www to route to non-www.  I have attempted to add an || clause to that If statement by changing it to  `<If "(-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https') || '%{HTTP_HOST}' !~ /^www\./"`, but that ended up creating some [www.www.example.com](http://www.www.example.com) routes.

Can someone provide any insight?  Is creating multiple  statements recommended?

Comment: Do you use load balanced EB environment?

Comment: Yes - classic load balancer.

Comment: Any reason why? If you use ALB, you can do all these redirections much easier.

Comment: I guess because when creating the environment, classic load balancer was attached... I saw option to migrate from classic to application so I might try this.